# sum of static properties not correct

Tags: c#, properties, static

I have this small class looking like this:

```
private static int field1 = - 1;
private static int field2 = field1 + 1;

public static void Sum()
{
    field1 = 10;
    Debug.WriteLine(field2);
}
```

A call to Sum() writes '0'. Why?

Comment: If you're going to update the question in a way that makes answers seem odd (e.g. changing what gets written out, and changing names) you should explicitly say so in your edit, to make it clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those aren't properties - they're fields. `field2` is *only* related to `field1` at initialization time - after that, they're completely independent fields. It's not like the `field1 + 1` expression is re-evaluated every time `field2` is read or every time `field1` is written.

If you *want* `field2` to just depend on the value of `field1`, you should make it a property:

```
// Note: I wouldn't actually call this Field2, of course...
private static int Field2 { get { return field1 + 1; } }
```

Comment: Glad it wasn't just me that thought it would return 0 and not 1, I thought I was missing something obvious!

Comment: And if you want a setter, `set { field1 = value - 1; }`

Answer (score 2):

This has happened because you are not updating prop2. You are only initialising it at the start.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int prop1 = - 1;
private static int prop2 = prop1 + 1;

public static string Sum()
{
    prop1 = 10;
    Debug.WriteLine(prop2);
}
```

This code never return 1,
Static property prop2 is initilized by zero.
You are not doing any operation in Sum() function. So it will just return inilized value which is zero "0"

Answer (score -1):

<s>you can't control the order of static variable initialization. If you actually want this, you have to it in a static constructor :</s>

```
static class XYZ{

    private static int field1;
    private static int field2;

    static XYZ {
        field1 = - 1;
        field2 = field1 + 1;
    }    

    public static string Sum()
    {
        prop1 = 10;
        Debug.WriteLine(field2);
    }

}
```

As Jon mentioned, I was wrong about my assumption.

Comment: Well, the order of static variable initialization is well-specified (at least for non-partial classes). See section 10.5.5.1 of the C# 4 spec: "... executed in the textual order in which they appear in the class declaration". So you *can* control the order of initialization, by changing the textual order.

Comment: Ok I was wrong. I still feel it's not a reliable way versus a static constructor. But as you guessed, the OP wanted a dynamic value, not a once computed value.

Comment: It's reliable, but fragile. (i.e. it can easily be borked by humans reordering things, even though the language guarantees the order for a particular build)